# dose bramus router have a routing limit ? how to fix the limit issue

Tags: php, router

So I'm using a php router to be specific this [php-router](https://github.com/bramus/router)
I followed the documentation and I wrote all my routes in
the index file as instructed.

Firstly it was working just fine for a while but when i add more route
the new routes wasn't working any more ( the new routes ), and when i move the newly inserted route code to the top of the file it works again but the other routes stop working for some reason.

My question is :
dose bramus router have a limit of some sort or any router in general ? because I didn't find much info about this topic

here's an example of my code :

```
<?php

// This file is where all the routes are defined using third-party router
// router : https://github.com/bramus/router


require __DIR__ . '/router/vendor/autoload.php';

$route = new \Bramus\Router\Router();

$route->get('/', function() {

#code here..
/*
Code like including/requiring files
running custom functions etc.. 

*/

});

$route->get('/route1', function(){
  // code here..
});



$route->get('/{page_name}', function($page_name){
 
 // code here..

});


$route->get('/another/route', function(){
  # code here..
});

// preview the content 
$route->get('/{post_id}/{post_name}', function($post_id,$post_name){
  // post route...
});



// custom 404 page 
$route->set404(function() {
    require( /* custom template*/ );
http_response_code(404);
});



// All POST functions here

$route->post('/post_route', function() {
   #code 
});


$route->post('/another_post_route', function() {
# code
});


$route->run(); # run all routes 


# end of `index.php`


?>
```

Let's say I wanted to add another route called

```
$route->get('/mynewroute',function(){
#code 
});
```

When I insert this line at the end of the file **before the run method** it dosn't work

but when i move it to the top it works but the other routes don't

so what is going on? is there's a limit of some sort ?

Comment: I'm guessing that's probably because you have `$route->get('/{page_name}'` before that already? That pattern would match a request for `/mynewroute` already, would it not?

Comment: I'm not sure, the `/{page_name}` should take arguments from the url but the `/mynewroute` is static and I don't think think this is the cause of the issue beaucse i also tried making all the routes static and the issue is still there

Comment: _"/{page_name} should take arguments from the url"_ - according to the documentation, these placeholders match anything - _"as they internally get translated to a PRCE that matches any character (.*)"_ And `/mynewroute` matches the regex pattern `(.*)` perfectly fine.

Comment: OOOH!, I think misunderstood it , i get it now, it's searching for a regex in the url like you mentioned that "as they internally get translated to a PRCE that matches any character (.*)", now i see why it's not working, thank you

Comment: But if should work, if you add your more specific routes first, and the less specific ones (using patterns/placeholders) after. If it finds a static route matching `/mynewroute` first, then there is no need to process any of the following routes any more.

Comment: is it possible to isolate the regex to that specific route to make it not affect other regex routes ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, "isolate"? // Placeholders appear to always use the `(.*)` pattern. If you don't use placeholders, but write your own patterns instead, you can of course try to be more specific with what exactly gets matched.

Comment: What i meant is the `route->get('/{name}',function(){})` or `$route->get('/(\w+)' , fucntion(){})` i don't want it to be affecting or matching any regex pattern that comes comes after it like `/mynewroute` or anything

Comment: like `$route->get('/{name}',function(){})` and after it it comes `$route->get('/route',function(){})` i dont want the regex expression to match the second route.

Comment: I don't think that will be possible, even if you changed the pattern somewhere, then the placeholder syntax won't work any more.

Comment: You should consider answering your own question. For posterity's sake, the answer is that the static routes (e.g. "/route1") will match fine as long as they are placed before the dynamic placeholder route (e.g. "/{wildcard}"). This makes complete sense, since putting the dynamic placeholder route *first* would cause it to match your static routes. The most organized solution for this is to simply use the first route segment to differentiate between dynamic routes (e.g. "/people/{person_id}", "/pages/{page_slug}"). If you really only want one route segment, then declare all static routes first.